# When does the stream function vanish?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, fluid-statics, potential-flow

I don't really get the physical meaning of the constant value that the stream function can take on. I mean, I know when $\psi = \text{const}$ that means that along that path the velocities are tangent to it, but I have seen that when $\psi = 0$ the non-slip boundary condition holds, i.e., ${\vec{v}} = 0$. Why is it so?

Comment: Can you add a reference for where you saw that $\psi = 0$ implies no-slip boundaries?

Answer (score 2):

The definition of the stream function is:

$$ \frac{\partial \psi}{\partial y} = u_x $$

and

$$ \frac{\partial \psi}{\partial x} = -u_v $$

for an incompressible flow. The precise numerical values of the stream function aren't important really, only the gradients are important. This means the flow field is determined by the stream function *up to an additive constant*, meaning $\psi(x,y)$ and $\psi(x,y) + C$ where $C$ is a constant both give identical flow fields.

Since the precise numerical value of the stream function doesn't matter, we can pick any $C$ we want. Some people may choose to make $\psi = 0$ on a wall because it makes some other analysis convenient. If I'm analyzing a recirculation region, I choose $\psi = 0$ to be the closed streamline surrounding the recirculation region (because it lets me divide "inside" and "outside" in a logical way).

In other words, pick any constant value for any streamline that will help your analysis and then the rest of the field is defined by gradients away from that particular value.